# How do I cast a type to a bigint in MySQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

`CAST()` seems to only work for BINARY,CHAR,DATE;DATETIME,DECIMAL,TIME,SIGNED,UNSIGNED.

I need to convert a hex string to a bigint, that is, I'd want:

```
SELECT CAST(CONV("55244A5562C5566354',16,10) AS BIGINT)
```

CONV() returns a string, so that's why I'm trying the convert it. I have 2 uses for this

- Inserting data, e.g.    `INSERT INTO a(foo)  SELECT CONV(bar,16,10) FROM ...` Here foo is a bigint column, bar a varchar. Perhaps I could get away with the select statement being a string and let MySQL take care of it (?)
- Returning data where the client will dynamically learn the data type of the column, `SELECT CONV(bar,16,10)` is no good as the client will handle it as a string.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
SELECT CAST(CONV('55244A5562C5566354',16,10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER);
```

Comment: So that converts it to a bigint/whatever ? I don't have to worry about overflowing an "normal" integer ?

Comment: @Anonym: in `5.1`, `CAST … AS UNSIGNED` always results in a `BIGINT`.

Comment: Is that documented anywhere?

Comment: @will: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert

Comment: @Quassnoi ... Thanks for that.  Unfortunately, `CAST` and `HEX` do not seem to be reflexive, I get: `1265: Data truncated for column 'uuid' at row 3`, when I use --  `CAST( HEX( some_bigint ) )`.  Just one of those things it seems.

Comment: @Quassnoi .. However there is No information about "BIGINT" on that page.  (I used a string search).  We have an example of an important capability, that isn't always effective (viz. my `Data Truncated` problem) that isn't documented and perhaps not supported(_??_). That's a hack.

Comment: @will: try using string search for "64-bit"

Answer (score 3):

What seems to be the problem? I've tested this conversion both on 64-bit and 32-bit system. Works fine. Note, that instead of doing hex to bin conversion, you can just treat the number as hexadecimal.

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(X'55244A5562C5566354' AS UNSIGNED);
+-----------------------------------------+
| CAST(X'55244A5562C5566354' AS UNSIGNED) |
+-----------------------------------------+
|                     2614996416347923284 |
+-----------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: cast('2' as BIGINT) --> _syntax error_ ... is the problem

Comment: I tried the following queries but it is still returning an error: 

```select max(value) + 1 from table;
SELECT CAST(value AS UNSIGNED) + 1 from table;
select CAST(max(value) AS UNSIGNED) + 1 from table;
``` 

```ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in```

Any thoughts?

Comment: ```
Expected Result:
98765123450987654321
```